# How can I do more flexible matching in conditional expressions than provided by LIKE?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

With LIKE '%' works but I have had no luck with character ranges, i.e. [0-9] to match a digit.

Oh for a regular expression ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this does not answer the question in your thread title, I guess it solves your underlying problem: There are regexp functions in the field calculator and other query builders:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Pro tip :)

There is a regex match operator `~` that will test a string against a regex.

```
'test5' ~ 'test[1-9]$' -> Matches
'test54' ~ 'test[1-9]$' -> No dice
```

**Note:** The `LIKE` operator also uses regex under the hood but it doesn't seem to work right.  I'm looking into it.  When you do `'test5' LIKE '%test5%'` the expression engine will convert it to `.*test.*` and test it as a regex.

Comment: Hmmm... i could not find tilde operator in my version of QGIS (2.01 on Mac) but it sure works!  Thanks! Better yet they appear to be pcre under the hood ;)  I missed the regexp_match as I was looking under the operators not the conditionals.